# Why does StandardScaler not attach metadata to the output column?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I noticed that the ml `StandardScaler` does not attach metadata to the output column:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature._

val df = spark.read.option("header", true)
  .option("inferSchema", true)
  .csv("/path/to/cars.data")

val strId1 = new StringIndexer()
  .setInputCol("v7")
  .setOutputCol("v7_IDX")
val strId2 = new StringIndexer()
  .setInputCol("v8")
  .setOutputCol("v8_IDX")

val assmbleFeatures: VectorAssembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(Array("v0", "v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5", "v6", "v7_IDX"))
  .setOutputCol("featuresRaw")

val scalerModel = new StandardScaler()
  .setInputCol("featuresRaw")
  .setOutputCol("scaledFeatures")


val plm = new Pipeline()
  .setStages(Array(strId1, strId2, assmbleFeatures, scalerModel))
  .fit(df)

val dft = plm.transform(df)

dft.schema("scaledFeatures").metadata
```

Gives:

```
res1: org.apache.spark.sql.types.Metadata = {}
```

This example works on [this dataset](https://github.com/MarcKaminski/stackoverflow/blob/master/datasets/cars.data) (just adapt path in code above).

Is there a specific reason for this? Is it likely that this feature will be added to Spark in the future? Any suggestions for a workaround that does not include duplicating the StandardScaler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While discarding metadata is probably not the most fortunate choice, scaling indexed categorical features doesn't make any sense. Values returned by the `StringIndexer` are just labels.

If you want to scale numerical features, it should be a separate stage:

```scala
val numericAssembler: VectorAssembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(Array("v0", "v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5", "v6"))
  .setOutputCol("numericFeatures")

val scaler = new StandardScaler()
  .setInputCol("numericFeatures")
  .setOutputCol("scaledNumericFeatures")

val finalAssembler: VectorAssembler = new VectorAssembler() 
  .setInputCols(Array("scaledNumericFeatures", "v7_IDX"))
  .setOutputCol("features")

new Pipeline()
  .setStages(Array(strId1, strId2, numericAssembler, scaler, finalAssembler))
  .fit(df)
```

Keeping in mind concerns raised at the beginning of this answer, you can also try copying the metadata:

```scala
val result = plm.transform(df).transform(df => 
  df.withColumn(
   "scaledFeatures", 
   $"scaledFeatures".as(
     "scaledFeatures", 
     df.schema("featuresRaw").metadata)))

esult.schema("scaledFeatures").metadata
```

```
{"ml_attr":{"attrs":{"numeric":[{"idx":0,"name":"v0"},{"idx":1,"name":"v1"},{"idx":2,"name":"v2"},{"idx":3,"name":"v3"},{"idx":4,"name":"v4"},{"idx":5,"name":"v5"},{"idx":6,"name":"v6"}],"nominal":[{"vals":["ford","chevrolet","plymouth","dodge","amc","toyota","datsun","vw","buick","pontiac","honda","mazda","mercury","oldsmobile","peugeot","fiat","audi","chrysler","volvo","opel","subaru","saab","mercedes","renault","cadillac","bmw","triumph","hi","capri","nissan"],"idx":7,"name":"v7_IDX"}]},"num_attrs":8}}
```

Comment: That's a very good point that I didn't consider yet - thank you!