# pyspark map feature names to coefficients

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I am running PySpark logistic regression trying to sort coefficients so I can take the most important features according to it.

Ghe pipeline uses FeatureHasher and StandardScaler .
when I try to map the features names with this code :

```py
transformed =  model.transform(TrainedData)
attrs = sorted(
(attr["idx"], attr["name"]) for attr in (chain(*transformed
    .schema[lrm.summary.featuresCol]
    .metadata["ml_attr"]["attrs"].values())))

vec = sorted([stage.coefficients for stage in model.stages if hasattr(stage, 
"coefficients")])
```

it fails cause there is no metadata in the schema, so it fails on :

```
KeyError: 'ml_attr'
```

why is it? How can I do the features<->coeff mapping ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does StandardScaler not attach metadata to the output column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44651418/why-does-standardscaler-not-attach-metadata-to-the-output-column)

Comment: there is no answer how to do this mapping in case i do use the scaler .